# Terraform equiv to Custom::LoadLambda in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, terraform

I know the equivalent to `AWS::Lambda::Function` is `aws_lambda_function`

But I'm not sure what the equiv for `Custom::LoadLambda`

I'm trying to translate the below into Terraform:

```
CreateRsaKey:
    Type: Custom::LoadLambda
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: # This seems to call another lambda
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - SolutionHelper
        - Arn
      Region:
        Ref: AWS::Region
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`Custom::String`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html#aws-cfn-resource-type-name) Resource Type refers to a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). This means that what it does depends on the particular implementation of the Lambda function provided to the [`ServiceToken`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html#cfn-customresource-servicetoken) property (`SolutionHelper` in your example). When a Custom Resource is used, the Lambda function is invoked with a [Request Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/crpg-ref-requests.html) specifying a [`RequestType`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/crpg-ref-requesttypes.html) of `Create`/`Update`/`Delete`.

The Terraform equivalent of a Custom Resource is a [Custom Provider](https://www.terraform.io/guides/writing-custom-terraform-providers.html) plugin. These are packaged and distributed the same as the standard set of Providers, only less officially. They are built as separate binaries (typically Go packages) auto-discovered by the core Terraform process using a filename convention (`terraform-<TYPE>-<NAME>`), and are invoked in a subprocess using a [custom RPC mechanism](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin). The plugin binary provides through RPC a [`Provider`](https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/helper/schema#Provider) containing a collection of [`Resource`](https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/helper/schema#Resource)s that implement `Create`/`Read`/`Update`/`Delete` functions for the resource.

So it's possible to re-implement the functionality of a Lambda-backed Custom Resource within a Terraform Provider Plugin by translating the CloudFormation `Create`/`Update`/`Delete` logic in the Lambda function to the `Create`/`Update`/`Delete` functions in the Terraform `Resource` (and adding an appropriate `Read` function). However, it's not a very simple or straightforward process.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this provider
https://github.com/mobfox/terraform-provider-multiverse